# Displaying item only on an osCommerce home page

Tags: php, oscommerce

I have a box ad in a `<div>` that I have put in index.php but it's showing up in almost all the other pages.

Which file do I need to edit or put this box ad in so that it is only visible on the home page and not on other pages?

Answer (score 2):

Well i found the answer

```
if ( basename($PHP_SELF) == FILENAME_DEFAULT && $cPath==null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the body of your index.php an extra class. For example `contentindex`. Also, provide your `ad`-div with an extra style element:

```
<div class="contentindex" style="display:none;"/>
```

And in your css it should be something like:

```
.contentindex ad { 
    display: inline;
}
```

Work with parents and children.

But why do you want this? If it's not allowed to be visible, why is it the div there in the first place?

Comment: Some older screen readers still announce items with `display:none`, though you did bring up the question on why this is on other pages and not just the homepage. Don't mind me atm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even thought its not proper you can edit the language template since it allows HTML.

It's in catalog\includes\languages\english\index.php You could use:

```
define('TABLE_HEADING_NEW_PRODUCTS', 'Your content here.<br />New Products For %s');
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Add it to the bottom of the index.php file in the catalog folder. Below

```
<?php
  } else { // default page
?>
```

Comment: The best solution is to use PHTML... "<?php if (<you_condidional>): ?> <you_html> <?php endif; ?>"